# discrepancy in the output of "swapon --show" and "df -h" for the swapon partition

Tags: swap

In my system `swapon --show` shows a swap size of 7.9G whereas `df -h` for the swap partition shows 3.9G:

```
$ swapon --show
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sda5 partition 7.9G 5.1M   -1
$ df -h /dev/sda5 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
```

`cat /proc/swaps` and `free -h` both report 7.9G but why the discrepancy in the `df -h` output?

Answer (score 2):

`df -h /dev/sda5` doesn't show the size of the swap partition, it shows the size of the partition containing the `/dev/sda5` block device:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
```

Note that it says "Mounted on `/dev`".

`df` only deals with mounted file systems, and swap isn't mounted.

Comment: So I guess `cat /proc/partitions | grep sda5` is the way to go about it then? (if one wishes to independently confirm the size of the block device)

Comment: Yes, that's one way of going about it. But there's no reason not to trust the output from `swapon -s`.